# How to cancel a core-toolbar on-tap event when clicking on a paper-tab inside the toolbar

Tags: javascript, polymer

When I click on the space above the paper-tabs in waterfall-tall mode I want to trigger a home function.

```
    <core-header-panel mode="waterfall-tall">

        <core-toolbar class="animate" id="core_bar" on-tap={{home}}>

            <paper-tabs selected="0" self-end id="paper_tabs">
                <paper-tab>0</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab>1</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab>2</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab>3</paper-tab>
            </paper-tabs>

        </core-toolbar>

        <core-animated-pages transitions="slide-from-right" selected="{{ $.paper_tabs.selected }}" id="core_pages">

            <section></section>
            <section></section>
            <section></section>
            <section></section>
            <section>My home</section>

        </core-animated-pages>

    </core-header-panel>
```

This triggers the home function but when I click on a paper tab the home function gets called also. How can I cancel the home function when I click on a paper tab?

```
<script>
    Polymer('my-pages', {
        home:function(){
            this.$.paper_tabs.selected=4
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
home: function(e) {
  // make sure this tap was on the core-toolbar itself
  if (e.target.localName === 'core-toolbar') {
    this.$.paper_tabs.selected = 4;
  }
}
```

However, referring to `$.paper_tabs` this way is not a good practice. Instead, decide that your `my-pages` has a property for `activePage` and bind the UI elements to that property. This way your logic and your template UI are *loosely coupled*.

```
...
<template>
...
            <paper-tabs selected="{{activePage}}" self-end>
...
        <core-animated-pages selected="{{activePage}}" transitions="slide-from-right">
...
</template>
<script>
  Polymer({
    activePage: 0,
    home: function(e) {
      if (e.target.localName === 'core-toolbar') {
        this.activePage = 4;
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

As a general rule, try to avoid using `id` at all in your template. That means your element is data-driven, and you can redesign your UI without touching your script.